# How to force all nodes in yaml to be strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a huge config yaml file, where all of the nodes should be read as strings. An example:

```
model_names:
  Audi:
    A4:
      - A4
      - A 4
  Fiat:
    500:
      - 500
```

I load out the file in rails:

```
catalogue = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/cars_catalogue.yml")
CARS_CATALOGUE = YAML.load(catalogue)
```

My problem is, that if I ask for:

```
CARS_CATALOGUE['model_names']['Fiat']['500']
```

It returns nil, because it thinks that 500: is a fixnum - but all of the nodes should ALWAYS be strings - and i don't want to enforce this with quotes everywhere in the yaml file. So how do I do this in a simple and smart way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringify_keys` should convert all keys to string

```
catalogue = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/cars_catalogue.yml")
CARS_CATALOGUE = YAML.load(catalogue).stringify_keys
```

Still better to use `YAML.load(catalogue).symbolize_keys` to convert all keys to symbols

Comment: But it only works on immediate keys of hash and does not recurse into nested hash.

Comment: The OP has tagged the question with `ruby-on-rails` so this fits the bill here, but this solution won't work in a pure ruby environment (`stringify_keys` is in `ActiveSupport`). Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Yes - you are right all three of you - the thing with stringify_keys, is, as mentioned, that it only works on the first level of keys - not nested and not arrays... So is there a way to do it on all nodes?

Comment: Write a fxn that descends into the hash levels and performs the operation?  That shouldn't be too hard, imo.

Answer (score 5):

Can you regenerate the file? If yes, then simply add quotes to the numbers:

```
model_names:
  Audi:
    A4:
      - A4
      - A 4
  Fiat:
    "500":
      - 500
```

That should do it.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't read the question, he specifically said: `i don't want to enforce this with quotes everywhere in the yaml file`.

Answer (score 1):

Rails currently has a recursive key stringificaiton function; [check it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_stringify_keys)

Comment: only available in Rails 4

Comment: @prusswan That is why I use the word *currently*. Rails is currently version 4. Also, note my link to the source of the function which can always be copied and used by itself.